# (2 Corinthians 10:5) trying to undersand what Paul meant by "destroying speculations and every lofty thing raised up against the knowledge of God"

Tags: 2-corinthians, spirit, demons

> 2 Corinthians 10:1-10
>
> 1 Now I, Paul, myself urge you by the meekness
> and gentleness of Christ—I who am [a]meek when face to face with you,
> but bold toward you when absent! 2 I ask that when I am present I need
> not be bold with the confidence with which I propose to be courageous
> against some, who regard us as if we walked according to the flesh. 3
> For though we walk in the flesh, we do not war according to the flesh,
> 4 for the weapons of our warfare are not of the flesh, but [b]divinely
> powerful for the destruction of fortresses. 5 **We are destroying
> speculations and every lofty thing raised up against the knowledge of
> God**, and we are taking every thought captive to the obedience of
> Christ, 6 and we are ready to punish all disobedience, whenever your
> obedience is complete.
>
> 7 [c]You are looking at [d]things as they are outwardly. If anyone is
> confident in himself that he is Christ’s, let him consider this again
> within himself, that just as he is Christ’s, so also are we. 8 For
> even if I boast somewhat [e]further about our authority, which the
> Lord gave for building you up and not for destroying you, I will not
> be put to shame, 9 [f]for I do not wish to seem as if I would terrify
> you by my letters. 10 For they say, “His letters are weighty and
> strong, but his [g]personal presence is unimpressive and his speech
> contemptible.”

Within the context of Paul Letters to the Corinthians as a whole, I'm trying to understand what he means by "destroying speculations and every lofty thing raised up against the knowledge of God"

Would the aforementioned bible scripture have to do with something like?

-demonic spirits

-Pride in the Human Heart( which could also be caused by demonic spirits )

-over-ambition to the point where it is greedy

-sexual lust

-overconfident

-arrogance
......
....

Answer (score 2):

Starting at vs3 the Apostle Paul is saying even though we walk in the flesh our warfare is spiritual in nature empowered by God.

So, since our implements of war are empowered by God we are able to pull down, overpower, conquer, and destroy spiritual strongholds. What are these "strongholds and fortresses?"

Such fortresses were the prisons for the minds of men. Since the gods of this world guard the bars that hold them, only spiritual weapons are more effective than theirs can set their captives free.

That's why at verse 5 it says, "We are destroying speculations and every lofty thing raised up AGAINST THE KNOWLEDGE OF GOD, and we are taking every thought captive to the obedience of Christ."

Now, Paul's reference to "casting down imaginations" and bringing into captivity every thought does not encourage mental warfare for the believer. True, things in the mind often trouble the conscientious Christian, and he would like to rid himself of them.

He surely feels condemned by them as the apostle did in Romans 7. But alas, victory comes through the covering of the blood of Jesus, as Paul found in Romans 7:25 and at Romans 8:1.

Paul determined (as we should) to bring all non-Biblical teaching he encountered into captivity. He captured and led away as a prisoner of war every philosophical system which was contrary to the view of this world set forth in Scripture. Personally, this is one of the reasons why I love "apologetics."